# How can I merge nested lists to output the key once and all values with that key "below"?

Tags: python, list, nested

`thing = [{item, abc}, {item, def}, {item, ghi}, {item2, jkl}, {item2, mno}, {item2, pqr}, ...]`

to output: item abc def ghi ... item2 jkl mno ...

I've seen similar questions but none that would help me. I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: Your data - `things` is not lists - they are `set`.  You may want to confirm and correct it.

Comment: @wwii I read the How to Ask, indeed this isn't a discussion forum. How about some active feedback? How can this question be rephrased?

Comment: you have list of `set()` with two values (not `dict` with `key` and `value`) and `set` doesn't have to keep order and it can be hard to say if you have `item abc` or `abc item`

Comment: Is this data more close to reality? - `thing = [['item', 'abc'], ['item', 'def'], ['item', 'ghi'], 
         ['item2', 'jkl'], ['item2', 'mno'], ['item2', 'pqr']]`

Comment: Try to solve the problem, if some part of your attempt isn't doing what you want come back and ask about that. The code you ask about should be the minimal amount needed for us to reproduce your problem - sometimes you have to make a complete new piece of code to focus on the question you are asking. Don't forget to included some data (even fake data) - we shouldn't have to go to an offsite resource. Don't post images of code, data or tracebacks.

Comment: Sometimes making an mre for a question can help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't forget to search - you are probably not the first person to encounter the problem. Search with Exception Traceback messages if you are getting one. READ THE DOCUMENTATION - Python docs and most frequently used packages have very good documentation - most  of that documentation includes links to the source code, don't be afraid to rummage around in the source to see how *they* did stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution like this could work:

```
thing = [{"item", "abc"}, {"item", "def"}, {"item", "ghi"}, {"item2", "jkl"}, {"item2", "mno"}, {"item2", "pqr"}]

newDict = {}
count = 0
key = ""
for s in thing:
  count = 0
  for e in s:
    if count == 0:
      if not(e in newDict):
        newDict[e] = []
      key = e
    else:
      newDict[key].append(e)
    count += 1

print(newDict)
```

Output:

```
{'item': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'item2': ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']}
```

Since you are using a list of sets, the solution is a bit more difficult than if you used a list of lists, since sets are unindexed.

However, we can still access the elements we order them in by iterating through them.

First, we create our `newDict`, a dictionary will store our output. For every set, `s`, in `thing`, we will iterate through every element, `e`, in `s`.

If we are currently iterating the first element, where `count = 0`, if `e` (which can be only either `"item"` or `"item2"`), is not a key in `newDict`, we will create a new key with an empty list as its value. Then, we will set our variable `key` equal to `e`, so that in the next iteration, we can append the value to that dictionary.

Solution if `thing` is a list of lists:

```
thing = [["item", "abc"], ["item", "def"], ["item", "ghi"],["item2", "jkl"], ["item2", "mno"], ["item2", "pqr"]]

newDict = {}
for s in thing:
  if not(s[0] in newDict):
    newDict[s[0]] = []
  newDict[s[0]].append(s[1])

print(newDict)
```

I hope this made sense! Please let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications :)